# A problem with kids and candies

Tags: combinatorics

**my question**

A, B, C, D, E and F are six children. These children are distributed n candies, n a natural number, so that: each gets at least one candy, A gets less than B, B less than C, C less than D, and D less than E. All children know these rules, they know value of n and, of course, they know how many candies they have received but themselves. They have no other information. What is the smallest value for which the n candies can be distributed so that none of the six children can know how the candies were distributed?

**my idea**

I tried solving this problem trying more and more combinations of numbers, until i found the right one.

For $n$ to be minimum, $F$
MUST be 1

Also,
$A<B<C<D<E$

The answer i got is when $n=23$ and the number of candies each kid got is $1,1,3,5,6,7$, this after trying all the variants

My question is if my idea and answer is right. Also, how can i demonstrate this answer without tries?

Thank you! Hope one of you can help me!

Comment: Can you please proof read the question part? I believe there may be some typos or missing words possibly.

Comment: @Nothingspecial Sorry. I edited the typos.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly $1+2+...+6=21$ candies have to be distributed at least... In this case, F gets $6$ (so the distribution becomes obvious). Try the next numbers: $22$, $23$,...

Comment: @Nothingspecial My question is if my idea and answer is right. Also, how can i demonstrate this answer without tries?

Comment: Your explanation confused me, you set $F=1$ whereas according to the question, F got the most number of candies. $A<B$ but according to the distribution you have written, $A=B=1$, isn't it?

Comment: @Nothingspecial oooo....its another typo. I edoted it. Sorry againnnn!!! It was E actually.

Comment: So $F$ can get any number of candies and acc. to that distribution for $n=23$, $F=1, A=1, B=3,\ldots$. Now the problem seems interesting.

Comment: @Nothingspecial Thats right. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I think your solution is correct. I am not sure how to demonstrate it "without tries". If $E$ gets six candies, he figures out the distribution. If he gets $7$, he cannot as there are two possible distributions... E getting seven corresponds to $n=23$.

Comment: Your proposal $1,1,3,5,6,7$ stands for $F, A, B, C, D, E$ and not for $A, B, C, D, E, F$, isn't it?

Comment: Is it the case that no child knows the total distribution of candies; or is it the case that no child can deduce what any other child got? (For example if B got 2 candies, B could deduce that A got 1 candy, but (perhaps) still not know the overall distribution.)

Comment: @paw88789 im not sure, but i think is it the case that no child can deduce what any other child got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shall denote the candies distribution when $A$ gets $n_A$ candies, $B$ gets $n_B$ candies, and so forth as $(n_A,\dots,n_F)$.

Let $N$ be the minimum number $n$ allowing to satisfy the problem condition.

We have that $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$ in total get at least $n-n_F=1+2+3+5+6=17$ candies. Indeed, otherwise they get either $15$ or $16$ candies. In each of these cases there is the only possible distribution, $(1,2,3,4,5,n_F)$ or $(1,2,3,4,6,n_F)$, respectively, so $F$ knows it.

Moreover, if $n-n_F=17$ then $F$ gets at least two candies, because otherwise the distribution is either $(1,2,3,5,6,1)$ or $(1,2,3,4,7,1)$. But in the former case $D$ knows the distribution and in the latter case $E$ knows the distribution.

Therefore $N\ge 19$. We claim that $n=19$ fits. Namely, given the distribution $(1,2,3,5,6,2)$, no child can know it. Indeed, the allowed distribution $(1,2,3,5,7,1)$ shows that none of the children $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ can know the distribution, the allowed distribution $(1,2,4,5,6,1)$ shows that $E$ cannot know the distribution, and the allowed distribution $(1,2,3,4,7,2)$ shows that $F$ cannot know the distribution.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to write a solution which proves that the smallest value of $n$ is $19$.

First of all, $n$ has to satisfy
$$n\gt 1+2+3+4+5+1=16$$
So, we have to have $n\ge 17$.

Here, let us write all the possibilities of $A+B+C+D+E\le 17$.

There are only four cases.

$$1+2+3+4+5=\color{blue}{15}$$
$$1+2+3+4+6=\color{blue}{16}$$
$$1+2+3+4+\color{red}7=17$$
$$1+2+3+\color{red}5+6=17$$

For $n=17$, $F$ can know how the candies were distributed because each of $A+B+C+D+E=15,16$ has only one possibility.

So, $n\not=17$.

For $n=18$, if $F=2$ or $3$, then $F$ can know how the candies were distributed because each of $A+B+C+D+E=15,16$ has only one possibility.

For $n=18$, if $E=7$, then $E$ can know how the candies were distributed because $E=7$ has only one possibility.

For $n=18$, if $D=5$, then $D$ can know how the candies were distributed because $D=5$ has only one possibility.

So, $n\not=18$.

Now, for $(A,B,C,D,E,F)=(1,2,3,5,6,2)$ where $n=19$, each child has at least two possibilities.

Therefore, the smallest value of $n$ is $\color{red}{19}$.

Answer (score 2):

What about the following:

$F = 2$
$A = 1$
$B = 2$
$C = 3$
$D = 4$
$E = 7$

So, $n = 19$.
If you tell a child from $A$ to $D$ how many candies they get, they won't know how $E$ and $F$ will get ($8$ and $1$, $7$ and $2$, $6$ and $3$ or $5$ and $4$).
If you tell $E$, he might guess correctly but he might also guess $F=1$ and $D=5$.
If you tell $F$, she has no clue.

... or am I missing something? (As I understood the exercise, you can tell each child the total number of candies and his/her own number, and from that they need to derive the exact amount for every single child, and as soon as there is one child they can't guess, the exercise is solved.)

Comment: Yes, that's right, you understood it corectly! Thank you! Also, may i know if there is any way to find the sloution without tries. How did you find the solution?

Comment: If $n=18$ and you give $7$ candies to child $E$, then he knows what the others will have. But with $n=19$ (adding the possibility for $F$ being $2$, no child can guess. I found it out, starting with $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ being $1, 2, 3, 4$ and then guessing further.